# Android Light Thmes

Tags: android, material-design

I am building an app to run on devices with sdk 15 and above. However I have a problem with the themes.
On api 21 and above, the appbar shows correctly as shown below
[showing appbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/390Ov.png)

on api-15 however, the image appears as
[the appbar has disappered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a7Ds.png)

The activity_dashboard xml is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>   

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.a.DashboardActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_dashboard" />
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar_layout"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        tools:openDrawer="start">

        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_dashboard"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_dashboard_drawer"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/white"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The content_dashboard xml is here

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.a.DashboardActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

My styles xml is here

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DrawerStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="color">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
    </style>

    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:animateOnClick">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Kindly help me solve this problem. Am using a light material theme.
Thank you

Comment: Then that could only mean that the UI attributes require a minimum API of 21 or higher. Could you post the XML files of the app bar?

Comment: I've edited the question, added the xml files

Comment: Thanks, but could you also post styles.xml? :-)

Comment: i've added the styles xml